# Delete lines containing a range pattern in 4th column

Tags: bash, scripting, sed, awk

In a file 4th column contains a floating point numbers

```
dsfsd sdfsd sdfds 4.5 dfsdfsd
```

I want to delete the entire line if the number between -0.1 and 0.1 (or some other range).

Can sed or awk do that for me?

thanks

Answer (score 9):

I recommend using the "pattern { expression }" syntax:

```
awk '($4 < -0.1) || ($4 > 0.1) {print}' test.txt
```

Or, even more concicely:

```
awk '($4 < -0.1) || ($4 > 0.1)' test.txt
```

Since {print} is the default action.  I've assumed that you have a file "test.txt" containing your data.

Comment: This kind of scenario -- line-by-line filtering based on a condition -- is really awk's bread and butter.  This was the type of use case that Kernighan et al had in mind when they developed the language.  The "pattern {expression}" syntax means that the "{expression}" is executed for a given line if the "pattern" is satisfied for that line.

Answer (score 3):

awk:

```
{ if ($4 > 0.1 || $4 < -0.1) print $0 }
```